# Grab json sent to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a command to post to a rails url some json:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"user":{"first_name":"firstname","last_name":"lastname","email":"email@email.com","password":"app123","password_confirmation":"app123"}}'  http://localhost:3000/maps
```

And i have a method create in my controller:

```
def create
    #@map = Map.new(map_params)
    #@json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(open('jsonfeed').read)
    @result = JSON.parse string #parse json, but where to get that json first
    respond_to do |format|
      if @map.save
        format.json {
          #render :show, status: :created, location: @map
        }
      else
        format.json { render json: @map.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

How do i get json sent to rails. I thinsk JSON.parse will parse my json and return hash params, but first how to get that json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following code in your controller and try.

```
before_action :parse_json_data_to_params, except: [ # Put Your Get Actions Names Here otherwise it will raise error for get requests ]

def parse_json_data_to_params
  params.merge!(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.raw_post))
end
```